# Compute smaller and bigger values for an array position

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I have the following problem I need to optimize. For a given array(with duplicated keys allowed), for each position `i` in the array, I need to compute all bigger values right of `i`, and all smaller values left of `i`. If we have:

`1 1 4 3 5 6 7` and `i = 3`(value 3), the count of smaller values to left of `i` is `1`(no repeated keys), and to the right, the number of bigger values is `3`.

The brute force solution of this problem is `~N^2`, and with some extra space I can manage to compute the smaller values from the bigger ones, so reducing complexity to `~(N^2)/2`.
My question is: is there a faster way to get it done? Maybe `NlgN`? I imagine there is a data structure out there I don't know which will allow me to do the computation faster.

**EDIT**: Thank you all for your replies and discussions. You can find two good solutions two the problem below. Always a pleasure learning from developers in stackoverflow.

Comment: Where is the code that has the problem?

Comment: (1) Please post the actual code you're using; it's much easier to understand unambiguously than a narrative. (2) This is probably a better fit for Code Review than Stack Overflow. (3) While you may be able to make significant improvements, going from N^2 to N^2/2 is a linear factor, so you're still O(N^2).

Comment: The problem seems clear to me, he is asking for a better algo than the brute force

Comment: The code for the brute force is as simple as it gets: for loop, with 2 others inside, one to right, one to left and counting. Thats all. And yes, im asking if there is a way to improve O(N^2). @ Zong Zheng Li can you elaborate? a hash set allows me to beware of duplicate counting, but i dont see how can improve the overall performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an `O(n log n)` solution.

As hinted by @SayonjiNakate, the solution using segment tree (I used Fenwick tree in my implementation) runs in `O(n log M)` time, where `M` is the maximum possible value in the array.

Firstly, note that the problem "number of smaller elements on the left" is equivalent to the problem "number of greater elements on the right" by reversing and negating the array. So, in my explanation below I only describe the "number of smaller elements on the left", which I call "lesser_left_count".

**Algorithm** for lesser_left_count:

The idea is to be able to find the total of numbers smaller than a specific number.

1. Define an array `tree` with size upto `MAX_VALUE`, which will store the value `1` for seen numbers and `0` otherwise.
2. Then as we traverse the array, when we see a number `num`, just assign the value `1` to `tree[num]` (*update operation*). Then lesser_left_count for a number `num` is the sum from `1` to `num-1` (*sum operation*) so far, since all smaller numbers to the left of current position would have been set to `1`.

Simple right? If we use [Fenwick tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees), the update and sum operation can be done each in `O(log M)` time, where `M` is the maximum possible value in the array. Since we are iterating over the array, total time is `O(n log M)`.

The only disadvantage of the naive solution is that it uses a lot of memory as `M` gets bigger (I set `M=2^20-1` in my code, which take around 4MB of memory). This can be improved by mapping distinct integers in the array into smaller integers (in a way that preserve the order). The mapping can be done in simply `O(n log n)` by sorting the array. So the number `M` can be reinterpreted as *"number of distinct elements in the array"*.

So the memory wouldn't be any problem anymore, because if after this improvement you indeed need huge memory, that means there are *that many* distinct numbers in your array, and the time complexity of `O(n)` will already be too high to be calculated in normal machine anyway.

For the sake of simplicity, I didn't include that improvement in my code.

Oh, and since Fenwick tree only works for positive numbers, I converted the numbers in the array to be minimum 1. Note that this doesn't change the result.

Python code:

```
MAX_VALUE = 2**20-1
f_arr = [0]*MAX_VALUE

def reset():
    global f_arr, MAX_VALUE
    f_arr[:] = [0]*MAX_VALUE

def update(idx,val):
    global f_arr
    while idx<MAX_VALUE:
        f_arr[idx]+=val
        idx += (idx & -idx)

def cnt_sum(idx):
    global f_arr
    result = 0
    while idx > 0:
        result += f_arr[idx]
        idx -= (idx & -idx)
    return result

def count_left_less(arr):
    reset()
    result = [0]*len(arr)
    for idx,num in enumerate(arr):
        cnt_prev = cnt_sum(num-1)
        if cnt_sum(num) == cnt_prev: # If we haven't seen num before
            update(num,1)
        result[idx] = cnt_prev
    return result

def count_left_right(arr):
    arr = [x for x in arr]
    min_num = min(arr)
    if min_num<=0:                       # Got nonpositive numbers!
        arr = [min_num+1+x for x in arr] # Convert to minimum 1
    left = count_left_less(arr)
    arr.reverse()                        # Reverse for greater_right_count
    max_num = max(arr)
    arr = [max_num+1-x for x in arr]     # Negate the entries, keep minimum 1
    right = count_left_less(arr)
    right.reverse()                      # Reverse the result, to align with original array
    return (left, right)

def main():
    arr = [1,1,3,2,4,5,6]
    (left, right) = count_left_right(arr)
    print 'Array: ' + str(arr)
    print 'Lesser left count: ' + str(left)
    print 'Greater right cnt: ' + str(right)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

will produce:

```
Original array:    [1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
Lesser left count: [0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5]
Greater right cnt: [5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

or if you want Java code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main{
    static int MAX_VALUE = 1048575;
    static int[] fArr = new int[MAX_VALUE];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = new int[]{1,1,3,2,4,5,6};
        System.out.println("Original array:    "+toString(arr));
        int[][] leftRight = lesserLeftRight(arr);
        System.out.println("Lesser left count: "+toString(leftRight[0]));
        System.out.println("Greater right cnt: "+toString(leftRight[1]));
    }

    public static String toString(int[] arr){
        String result = "[";
        for(int num: arr){
            if(result.length()!=1){
                result+=", ";
            }
            result+=num;
        }
        result+="]";
        return result;
    }

    public static void reset(){
        Arrays.fill(fArr,0);
    }

    public static void update(int idx, int val){
        while(idx < MAX_VALUE){
            fArr[idx]+=val;
            idx += (idx & -idx);
        }
    }

    public static int cntSum(int idx){
        int result = 0;
        while(idx > 0){
            result += fArr[idx];
            idx -= (idx & -idx);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int[] lesserLeftCount(int[] arr){
        reset();
        int[] result = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            result[i] = cntSum(arr[i]-1);
            if(cntSum(arr[i])==result[i]) update(arr[i],1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int[][] lesserLeftRight(int[] arr){
        int[] left = new int[arr.length];
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            left[i] = arr[i];
            if(min>arr[i]) min=arr[i];
        }
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) left[i]+=min+1;
        left = lesserLeftCount(left);

        int[] right = new int[arr.length];
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            right[i] = arr[arr.length-1-i];
            if(max<right[i]) max=right[i];
        }
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) right[i] = max+1-right[i];
        right = lesserLeftCount(right);
        int[] rightFinal = new int[right.length];
        for(int i=0; i<right.length; i++) rightFinal[i] = right[right.length-1-i];
        return new int[][]{left, rightFinal};
    }
}
```

which will produce same result.

Comment: This is a great solution, though you can't argue that `M` is a constant if you also assume that `n < M` -- or rather, if you do then `n` is constant too and your algorithm becomes `O(1)`. So I'd either argue that `M` is constant and we're planning for huge `n`, or express the complexity in `n` and `M`. Either way, nicely done.

Comment: @ErikP., and after 7 years, I updated my answer to remove that misleading statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try segment tree data structure used for solving RMQ.
It would give you exactly n log n.

And look through [RMQ problem](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor) generally, your problem may be reduced to it.

Comment: Care to enlighten? I don't see how this problem reduces to RMQ, nor is it obvious how a segment tree can be used to count the number of distinct values less than `x[i]` in `x[0..i)`.

Comment: It's elaborated in my answer, which uses Fenwick Tree in place of segment tree (both are equivalent)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a relatively simple solution that's `O(N lg(N))` that doesn't rely on the entries being among finitely many integers (in particular, it should work for any ordered data type).

We assume the output is to be stored in two arrays; `lowleft[i]` will at the end contain the number of distinct values `x[j]` with `j < i` and `x[j] < x[i]`, and `highright[i]` will at the end contain the number of distinct values `x[j]` with `j > i` and `x[j] > x[i]`.

Create a balanced tree data structure that maintains in each node, the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at that node. This is fairly standard, but not a part of the Java standard library I think; it's probably easiest to do an AVL tree or so. The type of the values in the nodes should be the type of the values in your array.

Now first iterate *forward* through the array. We start with an empty balanced tree. For every value `x[i]` we encounter, we enter it into the balanced tree (near the end there are `O(N)` entries in this tree, so this step takes `O(lg(N))` time). When searching for the position to enter `x[i]`, we keep track of the number of values less than `x[i]` by adding up the sizes of all left subtrees whenever we take the right subtree, and adding what will be the size of the left subtree of `x[i]`. We enter this number into `lowleft[i]`.

If the value `x[i]` is already in the tree, we just carry on with the next iteration of this loop. If the value `x[i]` is not in there, we enter it and rebalance the tree, taking care to update the subtree sizes correctly.

Each iteration of this loop takes `O(lg(N))` steps, for a total of `O(N lg(N))`. We now start with an empty tree and do the same thing iterating *backward* through the array, finding the position for every `x[i]` in the tree, and every time recording the size of all subtrees to the right of the new node as `highright[i]`. Total complexity therefore `O(N lg(N))`.

Comment: Yes, it would be a good solution but if i understand it correctly there is a problem: for an array 1 5 4 3 6 5 9 10, the first 5 has 6 as a bigger number, but the second 5 doesn't. So for the second five we would get a +1 value that doesn't meet the requirements. I think. Thanks

Comment: @user1812632 For the `highright` entries, you iterate *backward* through the array (in the second pass). So early on you encounter the rightmost 5 and see that there's one number that's greater in your tree (the 9), and later you encounter the leftmost 5 and see that the 6 and 9 are the numbers in your tree that are greater.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm which should give you `O(NlgN)`:

1. Iterate over the list once and build a map of `key => indexList`. So for ever key (element in the array) you store a list of all the indices where that key is in the array. This will take `O(N)` (iterate over the list) + `N*O(1)` (appending N items to lists) steps. So this step is `O(N)`. The second step requires that these lists are sorted which they will be as we are iterating over the list from left to right so a newly inserted index in a list will always be larger than all the other ones which are already in there.
2. Iterate over the list again and for each element search the index lists for all keys which are larger than the current element for the first index which is after the current index. This gives you the number of elements to the right of the current one which are larger than the current element. As the index lists are sorted you can do a binary search which will take `O(k * lgN)` steps with `k` being the number of keys larger then the current one. If the number of keys has an upper limit then this is a constant as far as big-O is concerned. The second step here is to search all smaller keys and find the first index in the list which is prior to the current one. This will give you the number of element to the left of the current one which are smaller. Same reasoning as above this is `O(k * lgN)`

So assuming the number of keys is limited this should give you `O(N) + N * 2 * O(lgN)` so overall `O(NlgN)` if I'm not mistaken.

**Edit**: Pseudo code:

```
int[] list;
map<int => int[]> valueIndexMap;
foreach (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {       // N iterations
   int currentElement = list[i];                     // O(1)
   int[] indexList = valueIndexMap[currentElement];  // O(1)
   indexList.Append(i);                              // O(1)
}

foreach (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {  // N iterations
    int currentElement = list[i];            // O(1)
    int numElementsLargerToTheRight;
    int numElementsSmallerToTheLeft;
    foreach (int k = currentElement + 1; k < maxKeys; ++k) {  // k iterations with k being const
       int[] indexList = valueIndexMap[k];                                            // O(1)
       int firstIndexBiggerThanCurrent = indexList.BinaryFindFirstEntryLargerThan(i); // O(lgN)
       numElementsLargerToTheRight += indexList.Length - firstIndexBiggerThanCurrent;  // O(1)
    }
    foreach (int k = currentElement - 1; k >= 0; --k) {  // k iterations with k being const
       int[] indexList = valueIndexMap[k];                                            // O(1)
       int lastIndexSmallerThanCurrent = indexList.BinaryFindLastEntrySmallerThan(i); // O(lgN)
       numElementsSmallerToTheLeft += lastIndexSmallerThanCurrent;                    // O(1)
    }
}
```

**Update**: I tinkered around [with a C# implementation](http://ideone.com/ni51ah) in case anyone is interested;

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. Your first part (as seen from the pseudo code) is putting **one** element to each array the key is mapped into

Comment: No, it records all the indices where each key is found in the array.

Comment: But this would be `O(n^2)`, since `k` ranges from 1 to n-1 right? Say for array with no duplicate.

Comment: `k` might just range from 1 to 9 or whatever the maximum range of numbers is in the array. Worst case it's 2^31

Comment: Yes, as you say, "it **might** just range from 1 to 9". If I have an array consisting of 10,000 distinct integers, your code would be slow as it's running in `O(n^2)`

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't change the big-O complexity. No one said it's going to be faster for all cases - just that there will be an `N1` such that for all larger values than `N1` the algorithm will be faster.

Comment: "That doesn't change the big-O complexity", so it's `O(n^2)`?

Comment: No, what I mean it doesn't matter that `k` can be large. As far a big-O is concerned it's a constant because it does not depend on the number of elements in the array.

Comment: If you insert an element into a sorted list, it takes `O(N)` time, so what you propose is `O(N^2)`. This can be repaired by using a balanced tree instead - then you get `O(N lg(N))` (for fixed `k`).

Comment: @ErikP. Hm well, actually the list will be automatically sorted because if we loop from left to right the indices will always be increasing. So nothing special required. And appending to a list is `O(1)`